# protogen - support the <Property>Specified syntax

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

After several years, I've upgraded my version of `protogen.exe` to 3.0.101.

The earlier version generated, for each optional member, a boolean property "Specified".

For example, my message had an optional boolean field `TurnScreenOnAndOff`.

The C# class would have two properties:

```
public bool TurnScreenOnAndOff {get; set; }
public bool TurnScreenOnAndOffSpecified {get; set; }
```

Using the later version of `protogen`, I get the following members:

```
public bool TurnScreenOnAndOff {get; set; }
public bool ShouldSerializeTurnScreenOnAndOff();
```

This has broken much of my existing code. Is there a command-line option so that the `protobuf` code generator uses the earlier convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. However, it is probably no more than a few minutes to enable it; the relevant code is in [`WriteField()`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/CSharpCodeGenerator.cs#L545), noting that `ctx.GetCustomOption(key)` accesses additional key/value pairs passed to the generator. This is possibly more of a GitHub discussion, though.

Comment: Thanks. I used search/replace with regular expressions so my client code now invokes the 'ShouldSerialize' methods instead of the 'Specified' property. My understanding is that the underlying meaning is the same. (Please correct me if I'm wrong on that)

Comment: @AndrewShepherd yes, the underlying meaning is the same (at least for the getter)